# set form error inside computed field

Tags: forms

I am doing complex calculation using computed field and trying to set form_set_error and  stop form submission, also filled values should be retained.

```
form_set_error($field_val, t('Validation failed'));
```

form_set_error() is showing message but form is also submitting without any break.

Also tried

```
drupal_set_message(t('Validation failed.'), 'error');
```

but no success.

Comment: I *think* (don't *know*, sadly) that it's because fields are computed as a part of save action, not validation. If I'm right, what you are trying to do is simply impossible.

Comment: What you're describing is exactly what happens when you use `form_set_error()` in  a submit handler rather than validate handler. Being able to set form error messages like that on submit is weird and wrong, which is why it's been [removed from Drupal 8](https://drupal.org/node/2241767). You'll need to write some custom code (in a module, not an evaluated text area) to handle this if the computed field module doesn't provide the functionality

Comment: @Clive is this applies to `drupal_set_message()` too?. Is there any way to raise exception manually so that submission breaks?.